# Django's Get Queryset as Generic Function

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Can It be possible if I create a common get_queryset and use it for all the class? If yes, what can be the drawback of this.

This --> `def get_queryset(self):`

Instead of defining it for each class, can I make it generic so it can be used for all the classes

Comment: It is not clear to me what you aim to do.

Comment: Please check now. I've updated the description

Comment: Are you asking about `typing.Generic` support for `get_queryset`? Like this https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/e4de8453cfbffa811ae5d3d0da7c83c7166c091d/django-stubs/views/generic/detail.pyi#L19 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a *mixin*, for example filter to retrieve only records with a field `active` that is set to `True`.

```
class MyMixin:

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            active=True
        )
```

Then we can mix this into other views:

```
class MyListAPView(MyMixin, ListAPIView):
    # …
```